# React Native Firebase Social Auth doesn't work on release

Tags: react-native, firebase-authentication, react-native-firebase

So, my app is already on Google Play and out of a sudden my social auth isn't working anymore. It works fine on debug and when I run --variant=release on the terminal, but it doesn't work when I download the apk from the store in internal testing. We've tested on several phones.

Email login works fine, only google auth doesnt work. Logcat doesn't show anything. I press the google button, the prompt opens, I select the user and nothing happens. Again, this only happens after I download from **google play**. What could it be?

We're using react-native-firebase and react-native-google-signin.

I have waste my entire week on this issue  and I can't figure out a reason.

app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'


import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
 *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
 *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
 *
 *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
 *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
 */

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

project.ext.vectoricons = [
    iconFontNames: [ 'FontAwesome.ttf' ] // Name of the font files you want to copy
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = true

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = true

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxx"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        missingDimensionStrategy "RNN.reactNativeVersion", "reactNative57"   
        versionCode 18
        versionName "3.1.2"
        multiDexEnabled true
        renderscriptTargetApi 28
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true

        // ndk {
        //    abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        // }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        // debug {
        // applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
        // }
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'


    implementation project(':react-native-firebase')

    implementation project(':react-native-android-location-enabler')


    implementation project(':react-native-background-geolocation')
    implementation project(':react-native-background-fetch') 
    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    implementation project(':react-native-navigation')
    implementation(project(':react-native-maps')){
       exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
       exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-maps'
    }
    implementation(project(":react-native-google-signin"))
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1' 
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'   
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.1.0'
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.5.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.2.1"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.1.0"

    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.9'
    implementation 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.21@aar'

      implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.10.0'






//    configurations.all {
//         resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
//             def requested = details.requested
//             if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
//                 details.useVersion '28.0.+'
//             }
//             }
//     }
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
```

build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion   = 28
        targetSdkVersion    = 28
        buildToolsVersion   = "28.0.3"
        supportLibVersion   = "28.0.0"
        playServicesVersion = "15.0.1"
        googlePlayServicesVersion = "15.0.1"
        androidMapsUtilsVersion = "0.5+"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com'  }
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral() 
        jcenter()
        maven {
           url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.26.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com'  }
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android" }
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }

        maven { url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native-background-geolocation/android/libs"    }
        maven { url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native-background-fetch/android/libs"}    
        jcenter()


    }
}

subprojects { subproject ->
   afterEvaluate {
       if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion 27
                // buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
            }
        }
       if ((subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android') || subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android-library'))) {
            android {
                variantFilter { variant ->
                    def names = variant.flavors*.name
                    if (names.contains("reactNative51") || names.contains("reactNative55")) {
                        setIgnore(true)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    project.configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                    && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                details.useVersion "27.1.1"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "Buzee",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.4.4",
    "babel-jest": "^24.8.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.54.0",
    "jest": "^24.8.0",
    "jest-react-native": "^18.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "android": "cd android && gradlew clean && cd .. && react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./fonts/"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "npm": "^6.5.0",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.8",
    "react-native-android-location-enabler": "^1.0.8",
    "react-native-background-geolocation": "^2.14.2",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-email": "^1.0.2",
    "react-native-firebase": "^5.2.3",
    "react-native-google-signin": "^1.0.0-rc8",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.22.1",
    "react-native-navigation": "^2.16.0",
    "react-native-progress": "^3.5.0",
    "react-native-rating-requestor": "^3.2.1",
    "react-native-side-menu": "^1.1.3",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.8.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "6.1.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "uuid-v4": "^0.1.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

this was the exact same issue that i faced. The built apk works but from playstore internal testing it doesnt.
Google has released a new signing service in playstore publish console in which google will signin your app with his keystore. After signing , it will give you a new SHA which you have to add in your firebase account .

[Google keystore place](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmLRV.png)

[image]

Now you need to copy those certificates from google developer console and log into firebase account , there select your app and go to its settings , where you see add fingerprint option, so you add the sha certs which youve copied from google into this. both sha1 and sha256 must be copied and pasted. and after that google login should work.

Comment: I think I already use google's app signing and it was working fine. I'll check on it anyways and return to you. I appreciate your help :)

Comment: Thank you for your help, Gaurov! You really saved me there!

Comment: Glad you made it :D

Comment: Thanks, the only thing that has changed is the location of the certificates. Go to Setup -> App Integrity

Comment: Thanks! you saved me from a bunch of users unable to sign up!

Answer (score 5):

In new Play Store Console, "app certificates" can be found under "setup-> App Integrity".
You need to add "SHA-1 certificate fingerprint" in your firebase console.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Solved it! Like Gaurav said, it was google's app signing that broke the deal. The thing with internal app testing is that it has its OWN SHA1 and SHA256 certificates.

So there are the certificates for when you publish and certificates for when you test internally. I only had to add those to my firebase app configuration. Those can be found on a tab under "Internal app testing" and "app certificates".

Hooray!

Answer (score 0):

To test locally, you should also add the SHA1 and SHA256 that are retrieved from running:

```bash
cd android
./gradlew signingReport
```

The command will yield many variants, the ones you want are `debug` and `release` - found at the very beginning of the output, right after the "*> Configure project ...*" blocks, inside the "*> Task :app:signingReport*" block. In my output, they're always the two top-most variants of the latter mentioned Task block.

The release one will only be useful if you've already setup a signing config for the release variant (more information at the [react-native documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android)). If you're just testing locally, the first one will suffice.

Again, they should be added in the Firebase Console, under *Settings >> Project Settings*.

Scroll down until you see the **Your Apps** section, namely your android app, and tap on **Add Fingerprint**.

Source: [React-native Firebase documentation - Google Social Auth configuration](https://rnfirebase.io/auth/social-auth#google)